# How to filter and grouped by id nested data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, reactjs

I have JSON data which has structure as follows:

```
const SubSpecs= [
        {
            "_id": "1",
            "nom": "installation",
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "idBlock": "1",
                    "ArtisanOffres": [
                        {
                            "idArtisan": "1",
                            "price": 12
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "idBlock": "2",
                    "ArtisanOffres": [
                        {
                            "idArtisan": "1",
                            "price": 14
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "2",
            "nom": "tech",
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "idBlock": "1",
                    "ArtisanOffres": [
                        {
                            "idArtisan": "1",
                            "price": 12
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "idBlock": "2",
                    "ArtisanOffres": [
                        {
                            "idArtisan": "1",
                            "price": 14
                        },
                        {
                            "idArtisan": "2",
                            "price": 50
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        
    ],
   
}
```

this is the array of artisans that i want to filtered by its id's:

```
 artisans= [
        {
            "_id": "1",
            "username": "test1"
        },
        {
            "_id": "2",
            "username": "test2"
        }
    ]
```

now i want to extract all prices that have the same id of artisan ( extract by id) and grouped by this id !!

i just start a simple function but i didn't find the way to finish it !!
can anyone help please !!

I am not able to understand how to filter such data ? Below code doesn't work I am not able to find any example of such filtering.

this is my function:

```
const total = data
        .map((fb) =>
          fb.blocks
            .map((b) =>
              b.ArtisanOffres.map((ao)=> ao.price)
                .join(",")
                .includes("1")
            )
            .join(",")
        )
        .join(",")
        .split(",");
```

i'm new in javascript and i face this algorithm problem,

Comment: You can not map over `{}` in JavaScript. Please revise your `data.map` example.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @Enijar i've revise my code

Comment: where is `username` coming from?

Comment: with your data, there is no way the string of the price can include the string `"5f0347634861448d28d8b165"`, so you get 4 times `false` (and with multiple prices in `ArtisanOffres`, they would be separated by `,` so no way either)

Comment: @NinaScholz i want my result to be like this exemple : [{idArtisan:"1",username:''test1",total:52}]

Comment: Yes but in your big JSON you have username anywhere

Comment: @Kaddath i've revise it , i just wrote an id to test thats all

Comment: What were you trying to do with this includes anyway? Now there's a strong chance you get 4 times `true` instead, try to comment this line for your tests. Where it is, it applies on the prices.

Comment: @Pterrat , username is a field in the table artisans , when i filtered the data and i found the id of artisan i will use username to display the user in the UI component

Comment: @Kaddath i just commited the line of includes and i got all the prices in an array but without speciafying the user , means it return to me all the prices not the prices by id !!

Comment: But `includes` will not help you group by id, try to use `reduce` or use a custom accumulator var in your map function. Aaah, trend of functional programming, what have you done to the youth? Basic loops with a result var would have been so simple!

Comment: @Kaddath i know u rite, but first i have to extract all prices by id , then group by this id and finaly calculate total using reduce,

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, what do you think about this solution? I filtered your data by idArtisan === "1", then sum all the prices. Result is 52. Here working example:

```js
const SubSpecs= [
        {
            "_id": "1",
            "nom": "installation",
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "idBlock": "1",
                    "ArtisanOffres": [
                        {
                            "idArtisan": "1",
                            "price": 12
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "idBlock": "2",
                    "ArtisanOffres": [
                        {
                            "idArtisan": "1",
                            "price": 14
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "2",
            "nom": "tech",
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "idBlock": "1",
                    "ArtisanOffres": [
                        {
                            "idArtisan": "1",
                            "price": 12
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "idBlock": "2",
                    "ArtisanOffres": [
                        {
                            "idArtisan": "1",
                            "price": 14
                        },
                        {
                            "idArtisan": "2",
                            "price": 50
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        
    ];
    let result = SubSpecs.map(sub => {
        return sub.blocks.map(block => {
         return block.ArtisanOffres.filter(artisan => artisan.idArtisan === "1");
       });
    });
    let array = result.flat(2);
    let final_sum = {};
    final_sum.idArtisan = "1";
    final_sum.total = array.reduce(function(_this, val) {
          return _this + val.price
      }, 0);
    console.log(final_sum);
```

Explanation: Used 2 maps (because SubSpecs and blocks are arrays) then a filter for idArtisan. `result.flat(2)` is because maps result creates a 3-level array. Finally a reducer to sum prices.

Comment: it returns array of 3 objects like this :  [{idArtisan: "1", price:12},{idArtisan: "1", price:14},{idArtisan: "1", price:12},{idArtisan: "1", price:14}] !!! it filtered but didnt return the sum !! what's the problem !!

Comment: Ciao, I updated my answer. Now you have an object (final_sum) with idArtisan and total price.

Comment: Thanks its works , thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: No problem. Have a nice day :)

Comment: have a nice day